# TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'attachShadow')

Tags: javascript, vue.js, web-component

I have this code in my vue component and when I build it as web component I got the error
**TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'attachShadow')**
I build the vue component with the following command
*vue-cli-service build --target wc --name web-stream './src/components/myComponent.vue'*

the template section seems like :

```
<template>
  <div id='stream'>
    <button v-on:click="startStreaming">
    Start Streaming 
    </button> 
 </div>
</template>
```

inside the section of methods i have:

```
methods: {
  startStreaming: function(){
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true, audio:true}) 
              }).then(function(mediaStream){
                let videoElement = document.createElement('video')
                let shadowElement = document.getElementById('stream')
                shadowElement.attachShadow({ mode: "open" }).appendChild(videoElement)

                videoElement.srcObject = mediaStream
                newVideo.play()
            }).catch(function(error){alert(error)}),                    
    }
```

i will appreciate any help, any suggestion

Answer (score 0):

In JS, anytime you see `TypeError: Cannot read properties of null`, this means you are reading a property or calling a function/method from a `null` (instead of an object).

This is where you need to look into:

```js
let shadowElement = document.getElementById('stream')
shadowElement.attachShadow({ mode: "open" }).appendChild(videoElement)
```

The problem with this is that there is no guarantee for `document.getElementById('stream')` to return a dom element or even simply your code run before the element is available.

It could be because of a miss typing, or someone changing/deleting the id attribute in the HTML.

Fix it by an **if condition**

```js
if (shawdowElement) {
  // your code
} else {
  // report "shadow element" doesn't exist
}
```

or using **Optional chaining (?.)**

```js
shadowElement?.attachShadow()
```

Read more about `Optional Chaining` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

That is for fixing the error.

But I believe to make your app run correctly, you need to identify why your `document.getElementById('stream')` returned `null`.

Comment: Thanks for your replying and explanation, I changed the code and I got the stream now, but now it's working without showing the content I can't see the rendered video content on the website I just listen that there's an audio do you have any idea?